# Solr Synonym searching not working while adding spaces

Tags: solr, synonym

As suggested in http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#SynonymFilter , synonym searching is not working when added white spaces in the synonyms i.e. the index word is "marketing" and the synonyms added are as follows:
abc, abc xyz, marketing

my schema  is as follows:

```
<fieldType name="String" class="solr.TextField"  positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
       <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    </analyzer>
       <analyzer type="query">
       <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
       <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"  enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

also i tried adding  `<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>` to  `<analyzer type="query">` but its not working.

Please suggest.

Thanks & Many Regards,
Lalit Joshi

Comment: Which result do you get and what did you expect? What does the analysis page under the admin interface say?

Comment: hi @MatsLindh , I do not get any result and What I expect is the result of keyword "marketing". Thanks